# How to manage the state and keep a track for multiple forms being filled out in Angular?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, angular-forms, state-management

In an Angular 10 App, We currently have a form as a stepper (1...2....3),
User can fill the form in steps 1,2 and 3, On the Step 3, we make a POST request to write to the db and provide with the confirmation.

Now, we want the user to be able to continue where he left off, User can start filling out a new form or be able to continue where he/she left off.

Also, the user can be filling more than one forms at a time and we want to keep the track of that and show the ongoing forms being filled out and pickup from there.

[This is the representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi6MU.png)

We were looking into State Management libraries such as RxJs, ngrx-store(Redux pattern) but that will be a learning curve and will add complexity, How should we go about managing this?

Comment: you can use reactiveForm and the form builder. that return a "form instance" and you can keep those form Instances in a service. and you will not lose your info until the user left the app or reaload it

Comment: Avoid any store patterns, if you learn about Angular dependency injection and shared services you wont find yourself in need to any sort of redux style store.

Comment: @adrian-brand - Might you have a link or something that expands on this? I'm not sure I understand and would love to hear more.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "right" answer to your question, only approaches.

The approach I take, leveraging Ngrx, is to hold each step's state by index:

```
// interface

{
  formStepIndex: number;
  formData: {
    0: IStep1Data;
    1: IStep2Data;
    2: IStep3Data;
  }
}
```

"Saving" a step is really just updating the data by index and incrementing the formStepIndex.

The form components are provided the data via an Ngrx selector that uses the `formStepIndex` to access the data for the current step.

This allows me to move forward or backward through the steps before they're finalized by POSTing to a service endpoint.

You could of course extend that to hold all of the above data in an array if you need multiple instances of a stepped workflow.

`IStep1Data` is typically a type, e.g.: `Pick<IWhatever, 'field1' | 'field2', ...>` to take a "base" interface that contains all of the properties and split them up into just the fields you need for each step.